# R. Fixing labels in pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using this script:

```
# my data:
df <- data.frame(Somatic = c("PIK3CA", "TP53", "GATA3", "KMT2C", "PTEN", "NCOR1", "ARID1A", "RUNX1", "NF1", "TBX3", "FOXA1", "ERBB2", "AKT1", "PREX2", "CBFB", "INPPL1", "NSD3", "ESR1", "AXIN2", "RAD51C"),
                 Freq_mut = c(32.6, 32.6, 11.9, 9.3, 5.4, 4.7, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 3.1, 2.9, 2.8, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6))

library(randomcoloR)

# set of 20 random colors
colors <- distinctColorPalette(20)

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Freq_mut, fill = Somatic)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  ggtitle("A") +
  labs(fill = "Somatic Gene") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
geom_label_repel(data = df,
                   aes(y = Freq_mut, label = paste0(Somatic)),
                   size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

But as you can see in the image, the labels are not in the correct position and are missing the rest of the genes. How Could I fix it and remove the "x" to the left of the plot?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be best with direct labelling here. Remember if you have a stacked bar graph, the y values are stacked, so your text labels also need to be stacked using `position_stack`

```r
library(randomcoloR)
library(geomtextpath)

# set of 20 random colors
colors <- distinctColorPalette(20)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = Freq_mut, fill = Somatic)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, guide = "none") +
  ggtitle("A") +
  labs(fill = "Somatic Gene", x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_textpath(data = df, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                   aes(x = 1.7, y = Freq_mut, label = paste0(Somatic)),
                   size = 4.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

or

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = Freq_mut, fill = Somatic)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, guide = "none") +
  ggtitle("A") +
  labs(fill = "Somatic Gene", x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_labelpath(data = df, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                   aes(x = 1.7, y = Freq_mut, label = paste0(Somatic)),
                   size = 4.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

To add percentages, you can try:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = Freq_mut, fill = Somatic)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, clip = "off") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, guide = "none") +
  xlim(0.5, 2) +
  ggtitle("A") +
  labs(fill = "Somatic Gene", x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_textpath(data = df %>% 
                  mutate(perc = scales::percent(Freq_mut/ sum(Freq_mut))), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), hjust = 1,
                aes(x = 1.55, y = Freq_mut, 
                    label = paste0(Somatic, " (", perc, ")")),
                size = 4.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that was really fast. Thanks for the advise! How could I add the % associate to each field? I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 3):

You should precalculate the positions of the labels so you can position the labels around the pie chart. Here is an option using `geom_label_repel`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)
library(randomcoloR)

# set of 20 random colors
colors <- distinctColorPalette(20)
df %>%
  arrange(desc(Somatic)) %>%
  mutate(pos_freq_mut = cumsum(Freq_mut) - Freq_mut/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Freq_mut, fill = Somatic)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = pos_freq_mut, label = paste0(Somatic)),
                   size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, nudge_y = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  ggtitle("A") +
  labs(fill = "Somatic Gene", x = "") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Allan Camerons perfect solution to implement the specified chart layout, I'd encourage to reconsider whether that layout indeed makes it easy for the viewer to grasp the information you want to convey.

An alternative display might help the viewer to associate gene(?) with mutation frequency *and* keep mental note of the top/bottom five "mutators" at one glance (if that's the intended message). By having the x-axis stretch from 0-100 % you can maintain if not improve the pie charts 'fraction-of-whole' aesthetic (angles being harder to compare than lengths).

Example (using your data `df`):

```
library(forcats) ## for convenient factor operations

df |>
    mutate(Somatic = fct_reorder(Somatic, Freq_mut, mean)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = Freq_mut, y = Somatic)) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = 100), stat = "identity", fill = '#e0e0e0') +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(x = Freq_mut,
                  label = sprintf("%2.1f  ", round(Freq_mut, 1))
                  ), adj = 0, nudge_x = 1, size = 3) +
    facet_wrap(~ Freq_mut < median(Freq_mut), 
               scales = 'free_y', ncol = 2
               ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100)) +
    labs(x = 'mutation frequency (%)', y = '') +
    theme(
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size = rel(1)),
        panel.grid = element_blank()
    )
```

result:
[image: pie converted to barchart]